# Xcode 6 Navigation bar is not showing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios8

I added UINavigationController in my xcode6. I have two view controllers. VC1 and VC2. I set VC1 as initial View Controller. I want to navigate from VC1 to VC2 and viceversa. I added a button in VC1 to navigate and selected ’Show’ option as action  . It is navigating correctly to VC2. But it is not showing the navigation bar. So i can not navigate to back.

If anyone have any idea Please help me.

Thanks in advace,
AKS

Comment: Your initial view controller should be your UINavigationController, VC1 should be the rootViewController of your UINavig...,

Comment: Thakns for your reply. Now it is working.